# How do I know when a car battery was produced?

Tags: electrical, battery

I have a hard time finding when my car battery was produced - can't find any defintive information.

The battery is Bosch Silver with the following data printed: `5EN` in huge letters and two rows of digits and numbers. The upper row reads

```
12V 55Ah 420 A(EN)
```

and the lower row reads

```
555 065 042   0 093 S55 51T
```

The embossed letters in the upper right corner read

```
G5B6882230170
```

With that data how do I find when the battery was produced?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is right: [Battery Date Codes](http://www.allpar.com/fix/batteries.html), it's out dated.

> The code is a string of letters numbers, but all the real information
>   you need is in the first two characters. Usually, the code starts with
>   a letter that corresponds with the month--'A' for January through 'L'
>   for December (some manufacturer's codes omit 'I'; for them, 'M'
>   indicates December). The second character of the code is a numeral
>   that stands for the year. Thus, a code starting 'A2' indicates that
>   the battery was shipped in January 1992; 'B2' indicates February 1992,
>   and so on. (Delco reverses the letter and the number; a Delco code
>   starting with '2C' indicates the battery was shipped in March 1992.)

Second source, which might be better: [How old is your customer's battery?](http://www.interstatebatteries.com/cs_eStore/content/resources/pdf/How_old_is_your_battery.pdf) (It's a pdf)

Check both to see if they have what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this to be correct.

G5B6882230170

6 means 2006, 88 means 8.month = august, 22nd day of, etc

Answer (score 2):

David is correct it left the factory in 2006 August.

The key thing is to know what to look for.  Batteries sold in the EU must be permanently marked with a means for manufacturers to identify production batches (if needed to recall a defective batch).  This requirement does not extend outside the EU, but as many manufacturers have no idea where batches may end up being sold, most arrange for batteries to include the information either explicitly - often on a label stating clearly the year/month the item left the factory - or in a code which is sometimes buried in a lot of other numbers.  A genuine Bosch silver Battery has a very long number laser etched into the case - such as GBC1110330337 290A 24 
Ignore everything on the printed labels.  With batteries what matters is the number laser etched or physically melted as a string of numbers/letters into the case.  To find the month of manufacture ignore the first three letters (GBC) it is the next 3 numbers which will identify when it left the factory. Then look up the three digit code here - http://aa-boschap-ru.resource.bosch.com/media/commonly_used_media/parts/repairs_and_service/_01072015.pdf

Answer (score 1):

actually you will read only the first 2 digits from this code "G5B6882230170" first digit means the month starting with A -> January and ending with L or M (as some of the manufacturers omit the letter I) for December and the second one "5" is the year of production.